# Store extending classes in different tables

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an abstract superclass which contains a `[Key]` field.
That class is then extended by 2 different classes which share this [Key] field, but have some fields of their own also.

But the problem is, when I create 2 `DbSet<>` objects for these 2 extending classes, they get put in the same table, and their fields get combined into that table.
So in my `Context` class, I have defined these:

```
DbSet<EmployeeAccount> EmployeeAccounts;
DbSet<PatientAccount> PatientAccounts;
```

I was expecting a separate table for each of these entities, but I got just 1 big table, and both EmployeeAccounts and PatientAccounts work with that 1 table (this leaves me with couple of columns in every row being empty).

I'm guessing this is happening because PatientAccount and EmployeeAccount have the same [Key] from their superclass.

Abstract class is really simple and looks like this:

```
public abstract class UserAccount : Entity<int>
{
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Username { get; set; }
     public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Extending classes are the following:

```
public class EmployeeAccount : UserAccount
{
     [ForeignKey("Employee")]
     public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
     public Employee Employee { get; set; }

     [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(24)")]
     public EmployeeType EmployeeType { get; set; }
 }
```

and

```
public class PatientAccount : UserAccount
{
    [ForeignKey("Patient")]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<FavoriteDoctor> FavouriteDoctors { get; set; }
}
```

Am i doing something wrong, or is this the expected behaviour?
If expected, is there a way for me to say to the EF to create 2 separate tables for these entities, even though they share the same [Key] field and superclass?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on whether the superclass is treated as (a) **entity** or (b) just base class. Looks like you want (b), so make sure there is no other entity class having navigation property of type `UserAccount` or `ICollection<UserAccount>` or similar. Also make sure there is no `modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()` calls or `IEntityTypeConfiguration<UserAccount>` involved in db context configuration code.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for input :)